# Asp.net - publishing a web site is causing an access denied error

Tags: asp.net

I am working in visual studio 2008 sp1 and trying to publish a web site to a local directory. I keep getting the following error :

Error   3   Access to the path 'C:\Users\name\Documents\Sandbox\BTNET\App_Data\BTNET.mdf' is denied.

My question is how do I determine what user account Visual Studio is running as? I have tried to give everyone, guests, and IUSR_ full control and I am still getting this error. It’s painful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must "run as Administrator" VS2008 and publish site

Answer (score 2):

Bring up task manager (ctrl+alt+delete) and look for devenv.exe.You should see the user in the User Name column.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK (As Far As I Know), it's ASPNET account

Since you're having problems accessing the DB file, make sure all the connection to that database are closed. That file might be in use, which in turn will cause the error.

Comment: I discounted the database and ran visual studio as an administrator and I was able to publish. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either an application is open and using the file(i.e. Visual Studio, modifying the schema or data or an instance of Access) or the user publishing the files does not have access to the delete files.

The first scenario is more common.